# Solve a very simple first order ODE in the form of an integral using Laplace Transforms. (5.4-5)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, solution-verification

I cannot duplicate the answer in the text book. Please examine my work to find the error.

**Given**:

Solve the following differential equation for $i(t)$ by Laplace Transforms. One initial condition $i(0)=0$ is given. The forcing function is only turned on when $t>1$.

$$100i+10\int i(t)dt=10(t-1)$$

**My Setup**:

Rewrite the equation dividing by 100 and apply the unit step function...

$$i+\frac{1}{10}\int i(t)dt=\frac{1}{10}(t-1)u(t-1)$$

**My Solution Steps**:

We now apply the Laplace transform across the entire equation giving us...

$$I+\frac{1}{10s}I=\frac{1}{10}\frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$

$$I(s+\frac{1}{10})=\frac{1}{10}e^{-s}$$

$$I=\frac{1}{10}e^{-s}\frac{1}{s+\frac{1}{10}}$$

Taking the inverse transform yields the following answer (for $t>1$)...

$$i(t)=\frac{1}{10}e^{-.1(t-1)}$$

**Answer in Text**:

$$i(t)=1-\frac{1}{10}e^{-.1(t-1)}$$

for $t>1$

**My Question**:

Where did I go wrong? I suspect my setup perhaps an error in applying the unit step to the forcing function? If that is the case can you show me why it went wrong and how to correct it? Thank you.

Comment: I'll write a post now.

Comment: What forcing function?

Comment: I think he just put a typo in the first line, it's there in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't transform the right hand side correctly.

You have the (integral) equation $10 i(t) + \int_0^t i(\tau) d \tau = (t-1)u(t-1)$.

From the equation, we see that $\lim_{t \downarrow 1} i(t) = 0$, but the book answer gives ${ 9 \over 10}$. Hence the book answer cannot be correct.

Note that the right hand side is $t \mapsto t u(t)$, time shifted by 1,
so the transform is $s \mapsto {1 \over s^2} e^{-s}$.

You have $10 \hat{i}(s) + {1 \over s} \hat{i}(s) = {1 \over s^2} e^{-s}$, and solving gives $\hat{i}(s) = {1 \over 10} {1 \over s}{1 \over s+ {1 \over 10}} e^{-s}$ from which we get
$i(t) ={1 \over 10} \int_0^t e^{-{1 \over 10} (\tau-1)} u(\tau-1) d \tau$.

Computing this gives $i(t) = (1-e^{-{1 \over 10} (t-1)}) u(t-1)$.

Comment: @Mattos and Copper.hat I wish I could have given you both credit for finding my error but I gave it to copper.hat because his was more straight forward and that is what I needed. I thank you both for working so hard on my problem. This sort of problem demonstrates that even the simplest of errors can get past experts in mathematics as yourselves.

Comment: I meant past anyone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you went wrong in your assertion that "applying the Laplace Transform across the whole equation [gives] us"

$$I + \frac{1}{10s}I = \frac{1}{10} \frac{e^{-s}}{s}$$

To simplify our problem, take the derivative of both sides wrt $t$ so we get an ODE and can use our Laplace Transform table. Hence we find

$$\begin{align}
i'+\frac{1}{10} i &= \frac{d}{dt} \bigg(\frac{1}{10}(t - 1)u(t - 1) \bigg) \\\\
&= \frac{1}{10} u(t - 1) + \frac{1}{10} (t - 1) \delta (t - 1)
\end{align}$$

Applying our transform, we find

$$\begin{align}
sI(s) - i(0) + \frac{1}{10}I(s) &= I(s) \bigg(s + \frac{1}{10} \bigg) \\\\
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{e^{-s}}{s} + \mathscr{L} \bigg[\frac{1}{10} t \delta (t-1) - \delta(t - 1) \bigg] \\\\
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{e^{-s}}{s} + \frac{1}{10} e^{-s} - \frac{1}{10} e^{-s} \\\\
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{e^{-s}}{s} \\\\
\implies I(s) &= \frac{1}{10} \frac{e^{-s}}{s \bigg(s + \frac{1}{10} \bigg)}
\end{align}$$

Using partial fractions, we find

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{s \bigg(s + \frac{1}{10} \bigg)} &= \frac{10}{s} - \frac{10}{s + \frac{1}{10}} \\
\implies I(s) &= \frac{e^{-s}}{s} - \frac{e^{-s}}{s + \frac{1}{10}}
\end{align} $$

Transforming back, we find

$$I(t) = u(t - 1) - u(t - 1)e^{-\frac{1}{10} (t - 1)}$$

**EDIT:**

The problem was that you didn't transform your RHS correctly. The rule states that (see a Laplace Transform table)

$$\mathcal{L} [f(t - a)u(t - a)] = e^{-as}F(s)$$

where

$$F(s) = \mathcal{L} [f(t)]$$

In your case, we have

$$\frac{1}{10} (t - 1)u(t - 1) \\
\implies f(t) = t, a = 1$$

Now,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} [t^{n}] &= \frac{n!}{s^{n + 1}} \\
\implies \mathcal{L} [f(t)] &= \mathcal{L} [t] \\
&= \frac{1}{s^{2}} \\
\implies \mathcal{L} [\frac{1}{10}(t - 1)u(t - 1)] &= \frac{1}{10} e^{-s} \cdot \frac{1}{s^{2}} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: There is no issue transforming the integral equation.

Comment: There obviously was an issue transforming the equation as the OP missed a factor of $\frac{1}{s}$ on the RHS.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there is no need to differentiate the integral equation in order to solve.

Comment: @Mattos 
Please explain how to solve without differentiating the equation because that is how the book does it. At least in this case it is not necessary to actually begin with a differential equation or to transform into one. Secondly differentiating results in a Dirac's Delta function and I am not up to that level yet but shall be very soon so I need be able to solve it without it. I believe the problem with my set up may have occurred with how I setup the unit step function. Please check that carefully.

Comment: @copper.hat Are you sure I missed an s factor on the right side? If you look at the first transform I had it. It disappeared when I multiplied the entire equation on both sides by s.

Comment: In non-homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations the right hand side, in my case 10(t-1), is often called the forcing function.

Comment: @JulesManson I'll make an edit to my post. Also, could you accept either my answer or copper.hats answer to close the question _and_ upvote both of them considering the effort we put in.

Comment: @Mattos Yes I shall tomorrow sometime and thank you so much for spending time on my problem.

Comment: @JulesManson: Yes, I am sure (about the missing $s$ in the denominator). Look at your first step after 'My Solution Steps'. I know what a forcing function is, I was asking what it is, because you have both $10(t-1)$ and $10(t-1)u(t-1)$ (or the divided equivalent) above. Also, note that the book answer given above cannot be correct.